# Clarification of "Maximum number of records returned by the server" in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis

What does "Maximum number of records returned by the server" mean when publishing from ArcGIS Desktop to ArcGIS Online?

Is this referring to the number of records of each layer or number of records in total?

So for example, let's say I have two layers:
Layer 1 has 500 records
Layer 2 has 400 records

Do I put 500 (the max of both numbers) or 900 (the total amount of records) under maximum number of records returned by the server?

Comment: Are you interested in restricting the number of records returned (helps keep the map responding quickly), or trying to set the value based on the features that you are publishing?

Answer (score 1):

It means the total number of records that you want to allow any one query to return.

In your example, you could say 500, because a query operates on one and only one feature layer. However, you might want to reduce that number if your clients' bandwidth or hardware are not sufficient to process 500 features efficiently.

Comment: Could you give me an example where I would use a query to return a record? Is this done in ArcGIS Online? I don't understand what this means.

Comment: Here's an example. When you add a feature layer to a web map in ArcGIS Online, the web map viewer will do a query against the feature service when you pan and zoom the map to find out which features to display. If there are more features in the current extent than the "Maximum number of records returned by the server," the query will only return that maximum number of features, along with the fact that there are more features, and the web map viewer will present a warning dialog to the user. Does that help?

Comment: What if you have multiple layers? Does return 1000 features PER layer, or in total?

Comment: It's per layer. Each query is only on one layer. If you have a map or app that uses two layers, there will be two queries at a time, each of which can return up to the "Maximum number of records returned by the server."

Comment: so if I have two layers, one with 400 records and the other with 500 records, and I'm publishing them together as a service AND I want all the records of both layers to show in the map viewer, I should put 500 under "maximum number of records returned by the server"?

Comment: Yes, 500 should work as long as you don't add any more features to the layer that already has 500 features.

Comment: I am finding that although this is set to 1000 by default my requests (e.g. https://<svr>/ags/rest/services/IPS860/QASQL2860/FeatureServer/0/query?f=json&returnGeometry=true&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&geometry=%7B%22xmin%22%3A-12816960.902858354%2C%22ymin%22%3A4314717.372641629%2C%22xmax%22%3A-12807176.963237852%2C%22ymax%22%3A4324501.312262131%7D&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&resultType=tile&where=1%3D1&inSR=3857&outSR=3857&outFields=*&callback=jQueryfoo) are returning over 3000 features.  Anyone else seeing this problem?  Seeing it in 10.6.1 and 10.8.1.